# React Axios - Pass Hook as Parameter for Axios Params

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, axios

I am new to React & Axios, I'm trying to work my head around how to change the GET instance properties based on user inputs... If I am going about it the wrong way please direct me.

I want the selected dataFormat to pass to the params of the Axios.getData()

At the moment I can only get it to pass the object rather than its value.

Thanks in advance

Here is the code to fetch the data:

```
function App() {
  let [responseData, setResponseData] = React.useState([]);
  const [dataFormat, setDataFormat] = React.useState("json");

  const fetchData = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log({dataFormat});
    api
      .getData(dataFormat)
      .then((response) => {
        console.log("Hello");
        console.log(response);
        setResponseData(response.data);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  };
```

Here is the Axios instance

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i0fJ3.png)

Here is the error I am receiving:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jDZlZ.png)

Comment: Access-Control-Allow-Origin header is missing in response from server localhost:8000, [read more](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Origin)

Comment: @HarshVishwakarma It is set within the API's get function, so when I hard code the data-type value it does not return this error